# Can't find Faralda

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can not get into the College of Winterhold](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80031/can-not-get-into-the-college-of-winterhold)

I never tried getting into the college of Winterhold until I needed info on the Elder Scrolls. I told Faralda I was dragonborn and she wanted me to demonstrate a shout. I did, and she thought I was attacking her, so I had to leave town. When I came back, the dragon was attacking. I killed it, but after the battle, and ever time ive been to Winterhold since, Faralda hasnt been on the bridge. How do I get into the college now?

Comment: Have you tried just crossing the bridge?

Comment: Solution is fairly simple, though I dont know if you still have a save file before this incident, if so, go back, use a shout that doesnt do damage or simply stand in front of her and do the shout in the opposite direction. If not, when you go to the Mage College, if there are blueish lights coming up out of the wells that are spaced out across the bridge to the college, then you just need to go to the college and find her

Comment: Yeah I tried going over the bridge, there ARE blue lights, but the door is still locked, saying I need a key.

Comment: And I do have a save file, I think, but I have done quite a few things since then I dont really want to lose...

Comment: Are you on a PC?  There may be console commands someone can suggest.  She *is* "Essential*, so she's probably not dead.  Although, it is possible she may have fallen through a hole in the map.  Have you tried waiting around for her?  Perhaps you're there at the wrong hour?  Have you tried looking/waiting around for Mirabelle Ervine?