# Can not get into the College of Winterhold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can not get into the College of Winterhold in *Skyrim*. I know I am supposed to talk to Faralda, but she is nowhere to be found.  I accidentally attacked a guard in Winterhold and now she is gone.  I can not continue with the Dawnguard quests without getting in there.

Answer (score 5):

She may have gotten herself lost during the commotion. Settle your bounty and wait a day or two away from Winterhold, then come back during business hours (just to be safe). If that doesn't help, follow Halfwarr's advice.

Comment: I cant get into the college of winterhold. I was suppose to go into saathal but i exited it because i got mad at this one dragor. So i thought that i would get stronger so i can beat him but now i cant get in saathal either. Any advice?

Comment: @Max you should post it as a question by clicking 'ask a question' in the top right corner. Also, what exactly prevents you from entering Saarthal?

Answer (score 3):

The only option you can do because you are on the Xbox360 and do not have access to the console:

- Reload to a previous save before you attacked the guard
- Wait/Rest 30 Days away from the area hoping the NPC resets

Answer (score 3):

If you have an outstanding bounty, you can skip Faralda straight and go into College of Winterhole... (it's one of the bugs)
Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Faralda

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to say you *have* ho go into the college to continue with Dawnguard; you can find out the location of the moth priest by asking inn keepers or carriage drivers.

Or, if it's the Elder scroll you're after, you can by-pass the college and go straight to [Septimus Signus' outpost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Septimus_Signus%27s_Outpost).